# Investigate the long-term behaviour of the population? [Leslie Matrices]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the following Leslie matrix $\mathbf{L}$ and initial population matrix $\mathbf{P}_0$:
> $$\mathbf{L}=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
> 0 & 0 & B_3\\ 0.25 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0.5 & 0
> \end{array}\right]\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r}
> 1000\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right].$$
> Investigate the long-term behavior of the population if:
>
> **a.** $B_3=8$.
>
> **b.** $B_3=4$.
>
> **c.** $B_3=10$.
>
> **Solution**
>
> **a.** Let $B_3=8$. Use your calculator to store the matrices $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{P}_0$. Then compute:
> $$\mathbf{P}_1=\mathbf{LP}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 250\\ 0\end{array}\right],\ \mathbf{P}_2=\mathbf{L}^2\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 0\\ 125\end{array}\right],\ \mathbf{P}_3=\mathbf{L}^3\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r} 1000\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right].$$
>
> **b.** Let $B_3=4$. Then a numerical investigation suggests that the population decreases over the long term:
> $$\mathbf{P}_1=\mathbf{LP}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 250\\ 0\end{array}\right],\ \mathbf{P}_5=\mathbf{L}^5\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\62.5\end{array}\right],\ \mathbf{P}_{50}=\mathbf{L}^{50}\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{l} 0\\ 0\\ 0.0019\end{array}\right].$$
>
> **c.** Let $B_3=10$. Then a numerical investigation suggests that the population increases over the long term:
> $$\mathbf{P}_1=\mathbf{LP}_0=\left[\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 250\\ 0\end{array}\right],\ \mathbf{P}_5=\mathbf{L}^5\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\156.25\end{array}\right],$$
> $$\mathbf{P}_{50}=\mathbf{L}^{50}\mathbf{P}_0=\left[\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 4440.89\end{array}\right].$$

This is an example from my math textbook. The question that I have is why did they choose the values $\mathbf{L}$, $\mathbf{L}^2$, and $\mathbf{L}^3$ for example a, but then change the values to $\mathbf{L}$, $\mathbf{L}^5$, and $\mathbf{L}^{50}$ for examples b and c.

Comment: When they change the value of $B_3$ the matrix $L$ changes and it is no longer true that $L^3 = I$.

Comment: For a), $P_3=P_0$, so from then on you keep getting the same three vectors over and over again, so there's no need to look at any higher powers of $L$, you know what's going to happen. For b) and c) you need to look at $L^n$ for large $n$ to see what's going on, since you don't get repetitive behavior.